# Подключение внешнего WIFI адаптера к Kali Nethunter

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux

Имеется samsung a5 2015 с nethunter и внешний адаптер tp-link tl-wn722n rev.3, ну и соответственно обычный OTG кабель. Как это все подружить между собой? Телефон через OTG "видит" адаптер:

```
#lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2357:010c
```

Нашел способы установки для Kali linux, но в момент установки выдает ошибку.

ядро - 3.10.49NetHunter_Kernel.

как определить какой точно чип стоит не смог, но драйвер использует  RealTek RTL8188EU

Comment: Вы хотите к телефону подключить внешний WiFi адаптер? Для начала надо на телефон собрать модуль с драйвером.

Answer (score 0):

RTL8188EUS.И да тебе правильно сказали, собирай из исходников своего телефона ядро, с патчем mac80211 вроде, и включи поддержку чипсета который тебе надо.(на samsung должен быть на оф. сайте), на дистрибутиве Ubuntu.Есть перевод статьи с гитхаба, инструкции, https://kali-nethunter.blogspot.com/2018/04/kali-nethunter_26.html .